# Formating values in between of arrays Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, iteration

I am trying to code a function where it checks if the `Numbers` elements are between the `Formating` values. So for the first element of `Numbers` 3 is not between the first and the second element `0, 2` of `Formating` so it returns 0 as the `result`. For the elements `3,4` in `Numbers` are between `2 ,5` so it return those `3,4` as the numbers between 2,5. The `index` value keeps on getting incremented until the end of the `Formating` array. How could I fix the function below so it gives the expected output, without a for loop.

```
Numbers = np.array([3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10,20])
Formating = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15, 22])

#previouse and curent index values 
prevs = np.arange(0,len(Formating)-1,1)
currents = np.arange(1,len(Formating),1)
index = 0

np.where(Formating[prevs[index]] <= Numbers < Formating[currents[index]], Numbers, ++index)
```

Expected Output:

```
Numbers between 0,2 = 0
Numbers between 2,5 = 3,4
Numbers between 5,12 = 5,7,8,10
Numbers between 12,15 = 0
Numbers between 15,22 = 20
```

Comment: Something with `np.histogram(Numbers, bins=Formating)` or `np.digitize(Numbers, Formating)`?

Comment: Usually `formatting` refers to converting numbers to strings, as in `%d`%3` or `{}.format(3)`.  Your use of `Formating` as an array, as though it means something, is misleading, and may discourage useful answers.  `Numbers` isn't that great of a variable either (it looks more like a class name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort then search sorted and it will run more efficiently (except for the IO)

```py
Numbers = np.array([3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10,20])
Formating = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15, 22])
x = np.sort(Numbers);
l = np.searchsorted(x, Formating, side='left')

for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[i] >= l[i+1]:
        print('Numbers between %d,%d = _0_' % (Formating[i], Formating[i+1]))
    else:
        print('Numbers between %d,%d = %s' % (Formating[i], Formating[i+1], ','.join(map(str, list(x[l[i]:l[i+1]])))))
```