# Checking in between values with Numpy PYthon

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am trying to convert the code down below to the Numpy version. The vanilla python code checks the previous and current values of `Formating` and checks to see if any of the `Numbers` values are in between them. The Numpy version of this code is faulty how would i be able to fix it? The code was gotten from the issue:[issue link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66571415/formating-values-in-between-of-arrays-numpy-python)

Values:

```
Numbers = np.array([3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10,20])
Formating = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15, 22])
x = np.sort(Numbers);
l = np.searchsorted(x, Formating, side='left')
```

Vanilla Python:

```
for i in range(len(l)-1):
    if l[i] >= l[i+1]:
        print('Numbers between %d,%d = _0_' % (Formating[i], Formating[i+1]))
    else:
        print('Numbers between %d,%d = %s' % (Formating[i], Formating[i+1], ','.join(map(str, list(x[l[i]:l[i+1]])))))
```

Numpy Version:

```
L_index = np.arange(0, len(l)-1, 1)
result= np.where(l[L_index] >= l[L_index+1], 0 , l )
```

Expected output:

```
[0]
[3 4]
[5 7 8 10]
[0]
[20]
```

Comment: If you expect lists (or arrays)that differ in length, that's a good indication that a 'pure' numpy option isn't possible.  Arrays are 'rectangular', not 'raggeded'. There are tricks that can create padded arrays or masked ones.

Comment: `(Numbers[:,None]>=Formats[:-1]) & (Numbers[:,None]<=Formats[1:])` might be a useful first step.  It should be a 2d boolean array, with True where numbers fall in the desired format range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from a previous question:

```
In [173]: Numbers = np.array([3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10,20])
     ...: Formating = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15, 22])
     ...: x = np.sort(Numbers);
     ...: l = np.searchsorted(x, Formating, side='left')
     ...: 
In [174]: l
Out[174]: array([0, 0, 2, 6, 6, 7])
In [175]: for i in range(len(l)-1):
     ...:     if l[i] >= l[i+1]:
     ...:         print('Numbers between %d,%d = _0_' % (Formating[i], Formating[i+1]))
     ...:     else:
     ...:         print('Numbers between %d,%d = %s' % (Formating[i], Formating[i+1], ','.jo
     ...: in(map(str, list(x[l[i]:l[i+1]])))))
     ...: 
Numbers between 0,2 = _0_
Numbers between 2,5 = 3,4
Numbers between 5,12 = 5,7,8,10
Numbers between 12,15 = _0_
Numbers between 15,22 = 20
```

Something that works fine with lists - in fact faster with lists than arrays:

```
In [182]: for i in range(len(Formating)-1):
     ...:     print([x for x in Numbers if (Formating[i]<=x<Formating[i+1])])
     ...: 
[]
[3, 4]
[5, 7, 8, 10]
[]
[20]
```

A version with iteration on `Formating`, but not `Numbers`.  Rather similar to the version using `searchsorted`.  I'm not sure which will be faster:

```
In [177]: for i in range(len(Formating)-1):
     ...:     idx = (Formating[i]<=Numbers)&(Numbers<Formating[i+1])
     ...:     print(Numbers[idx])
     ...: 
[]
[3 4]
[ 5  7  8 10]
[]
[20]
```

We could get the `idx` mask for all values of `Formating` at once:

```
In [183]: mask=(Formating[:-1,None]<=Numbers)&(Numbers<Formating[1:,None])
In [184]: mask
Out[184]: 
array([[False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False,  True]])
In [185]: N=Numbers[:,None].repeat(5,1).T   # 5 = len(Formating)-1
In [186]: N
Out[186]: 
array([[ 3,  4,  5,  7,  8, 10, 20],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  7,  8, 10, 20],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  7,  8, 10, 20],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  7,  8, 10, 20],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  7,  8, 10, 20]])
In [187]: np.ma.masked_array(N,~mask)
Out[187]: 
masked_array(
  data=[[--, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [3, 4, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, 5, 7, 8, 10, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, --],
        [--, --, --, --, --, --, 20]],
  mask=[[ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False]],
  fill_value=999999)
```

Your lists are apparent there.  But the list display still requires iteraiton:

```
In [188]: for row in mask:
     ...:     print(Numbers[row])
[]
[3 4]
[ 5  7  8 10]
[]
[20]
```

I'll let you time test these alternatives with this or more realistic data.  I suspect a pure list version is fastest for small problems, but I'm not sure how the others will scale.

### edit

Following questions ask about sums.  `np.ma.sum`, or the masked arrays own `sum` method, sums the unmasked values, effectively filling the masked values with 0.

```
In [253]: np.ma.masked_array(N,~mask).sum(axis=1)
Out[253]: 
masked_array(data=[--, 7, 30, --, 20],
             mask=[ True, False, False,  True, False],
       fill_value=999999)

In [256]: np.ma.masked_array(N,~mask).filled(0)
Out[256]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  5,  7,  8, 10,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20]])
```

Actually we don't need to use the masked array mechanism to get here (though it can be nice visually):

```
In [258]: N*mask
Out[258]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 3,  4,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  5,  7,  8, 10,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 20]])
In [259]: (N*mask).sum(axis=1)
Out[259]: array([ 0,  7, 30,  0, 20])
```

Comment: is there a way so that I could replace the `--`  for zeroes fin the masked array. I tried implementing `np.where(result != "--", result, 0)`, whoever it does work. it is the last example of your answer.

Comment: When iterating over the rows (print lines) just do a test for `[]` and substitue what you want.  But any such tweak moves you further away from a 'pure' numpy solution. Matching the length of the list wjth the number of matches is the most logical choice.