# Working with 2 arrays with different lengths Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, size

Is there a way I could modify the function down below so that it could compute arrays with different length sizes. the length of `Numbers` array is 7 and the length of the `Formating` is 5. The code down below compares if any number in `Formating` is between two values and if it the case then it sums the values that are in between. So for the first calculation since no element in `Numbers` is between `0, 2` the result will be 0. Link to code was derived from: [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575451/checking-in-between-values-with-numpy-python/66577346?noredirect=1#comment117715969_66577346).

Code:

```
Numbers = np.array([3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10,20])
Formating = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15])
x = np.sort(Numbers);
l = np.searchsorted(x, Formating, side='left')
mask=(Formating[:-1,None]<=Numbers)&(Numbers<Formating[1:,None])
N=Numbers[:,None].repeat(5,1).T
result= np.ma.masked_array(N,~mask)
result = result.filled(0)
result = np.sum(result, axis=1)
```

Expected output:

```
[ 0  7 30  0]
```

Comment: What's wrong with that code?

Comment: @hpaulj it doesn't run :-). Should have been `N=Numbers[:,None].repeat(4,1).T`. That said `x` and `l` are redudant, and wrong!

Comment: and all that `result` stuff seems overkilled. `(mask * Numbers[None, :]).sum(axis=1)` works fine. That said, this series of questions from OP look like an XY-problem.

Comment: `x` and `l`  are from a different solution, `mask` is what I proposed.  The use of `5` in `N` is left over from when `Formatting` had 6 terms; obviously (?) if `Formating` is changed this value should as well.  I suggested the `np.ma` as a way of visualizing the use of `mask`.  `np.ma.sum` would have taken care of the 0 fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `bincounts`. Note that you have your `x` and `l` messed-up, and I recalled that you could/should use `digitize`:

```
# Formating goes here
x = np.sort(Formating);

# digitize
l = np.digitize(Numbers, x)

# output:
np.bincount(l, weights=Numbers)
```

Out:

```
array([ 0.,  0.,  7., 30.,  0., 20.])
```

Comment: Is there  a way i could modify the output to be between the set boundaries and result in `[ 0  7 30  0]`