# Formating numpy arrays to find the sum betyween 2 values Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, sum

I am trying to modify the values of the values down below to the expected values. The function down below is meant to sum out all the values between 2 consecutive elements of `limits`. none of the values are between `0 and 2` within `Numbers` so the resultant is 0. However the values between `2 and 5` are `3,4` within `Numbers` so the resultant is `3+4=7`. The function has been gotten from issue: [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66593076/working-with-2-arrays-with-different-lengths-numpy-python).

```
def formating(a, b):
    
    # Formating goes here
    x = np.sort(b);
    # digitize
    l = np.digitize(a, x)
    # output:
    result = np.bincount(l, weights=a)
    return result

Numbers = np.array([3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10,20])
limit1 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15])
limit2 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12])
limit3 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15, 22])

result1= formating(Numbers, limit1)
result2= formating(Numbers, limit2)
result3= formating(Numbers, limit3)
```

Current output

```
result1:  [ 0.  0.  7. 30.  0. 20.] 
result2:  [ 0.  0.  7. 30. 20.] 
result3:  [ 0.  0.  7. 30.  0. 20.]
```

Wanted Output:

```
result1:  [ 0.  7. 30.  0.] 
result2:  [ 0.  7. 30. ] 
result3:  [ 0.  7. 30.  0. 20.]
```

Comment: Please explain the question, as it is unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: which bit is hard to recall, it goes through 2 elements at a  time in `Numbers` like for example 0 and 2. The first and the second element in `limit1 - 3`. If there arent any values in between 0 and 2 which there arent since all the elements of `Numbers` is  >  2. It gives out 0 as the result. If the `Numbers` values are in range then it will add up all the `Numbers` elements.Hopefully thats more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just throw out the bins for numbers off the end.

```
result1 = result1[1:len(limit1)]
result2 = result2[1:len(limit2)]
result3 = result3[1:len(limit3)]
```

Or, for smarter results, end the function with:

```
    result = np.bincount(1, weights=a)
    return result[1:len(b)]
```

Comment: Hi I made another post that is kind of related to this question if you could take a look at it II would appreciate it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66609006/formating-multidimensional-numpy-arrays-to-find-the-sum-betyween-2-values-python