# Formating multidimensional numpy arrays to find the sum betyween 2 values Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, multidimensional-array

The function down below is meant to sum out all second row values of `Numbers[:,0]` between 2 consecutive elements of limits `limit1-3`. For the first calculation if none of the values are between 0 and 2 (the first two elements of `limit1`) within Numbers so the resultant is 0. For the second calculation `3,4` within `Numbers[:,0]` is between the values `2-5` in `limit1` so the second column of `Numbers` is summed up `1+3 =4` resulting in 4. How could I implement this to the function below?

```
def formating(a, b, c):
    
    # Formating goes here
    x = np.sort(c);
    # digitize
    l = np.digitize(a, x)
    # output:
    result = np.bincount(l, weights=b)
    return result[1:len(b)]

Numbers = np.array([[3,1], [4,3], [5,3], [7,11], [8,9], [10,20] , [20, 45]])
limit1 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15])
limit2 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12])
limit3 = np.array([0, 2 , 5, 12, 15, 22])

result1= formating(Numbers[:,0], Numbers[:,1], limit1)
result2= formating(Numbers[:,0], Numbers[:,1], limit2)
result3= formating(Numbers[:,0], Numbers[:,1], limit3)
```

Expected Output

```
result1:  [ 0.  4. 43.  0. ] 
result2:  [ 0.  4. 43. ] 
result3:  [ 0.  4. 43.  0. 45.]
```

Current Output

```
result1:  [ 0.  4. 43.  0. 45.] 
result2:  [ 0.  4. 43. 45.] 
result3:  [ 0.  4. 43.  0. 45.]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
    return result[1:len(b)]
```

should be

```
    return result[1:len(c)]
```

Your return vector is dependent on the length of your bins, not your input data.